# Implement Generic BaseClass<T> which is derived from another Base class

Tags: c#, generics

Consider, TableController is a class exists one of the nuget package library (Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables).  In order to create own Controller, we need to inherit the class and write our methods like GetAll, GetSingle etc.,

```
public class OrderController : TableController<Order>
{
        public IQueryable<Order> GetAll()
        {
            return Query();
        }
        public SingleResult<Order> GetSingle(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }
        public Task Delete(string id)
        {
            return DeleteAsync(id);
        }
        //More methods here
}
```

I need to write other controllers where the methods are common for Get, Update, Delete.  I thought of using Generic base class which will can something like below:  Idea is to re-use the common code into a base class

```
public class OrderController : BaseController<User>
{
}

public class BaseController<T> : TableController<T> where T: class
{
        //All common methods like GetAll, GetSingle can be here with Type T  

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return Query();
        }
        public SingleResult<T> GetSingle(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }
        public Task Delete(string id)
        {
            return DeleteAsync(id);
        }
        //More methods here
}
```

But It will give compile error as expected.  Is there away to achieve the generic base class in this case?

**Edited:**
Adding error screen
[image]

Comment: `I tried but not works` - can you elaborate..?

Comment: You're code doesn't compile.  This isn't valid: `BaseController<T : TableController<T> where T: class`

Comment: @rory.ap: I think that's the point OP is making

Comment: So basic syntax error?

Comment: @rory.ap: yes, but requesting a fix for this pattern

Comment: I assumed typo tbh

Comment: @rory.ap It gives compile error.  Just want a solution for the case.

Comment: Without seeing the definition of TableController<TData>, I can't be sure, but based on available information, TableController<TData> appears to have a generic type constraint on it. If that is the case, the implementing class (BaseController<T>) has to have an explicit constraint that matches that of TableController<TData>.

Comment: In the code you've posted there is the `class` constraint, but it doesn't appear in the image (also the `abstract` modifier). Are you sure its there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : TableController<T>
{
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            //Some code here...
        }

        // GET T/TodoItem
        public IQueryable<T> GetAllTodoItems()
        {
              // your code here. T will be the right type but it'll be near on useless
        }
        //More methods here
}
```

Which you would implement as:

```
public class OrderController : BaseController<Order>
{
}
```

Note that if `TableController` constrains `T` you must have an appropriate constraint on `BaseController`

---

Edit: I don't believe this will be useful to you. But the code will compile.

Comment: @Stefan if it *needs* to be, but nothing indicates why `Order` couldnt be  a struct

Comment: depends on constraints on `TableController<T>`

Comment: Thanks.  But all the code in the OrderController is common.  I do not want to override it..  Just required simple derived class

Comment: If you dont want to change the behaviour, theres no point having a base class. You just have 1 class. But thanks for the downvote. Your `GetAllTodoItems` needs to know what type of object to return, so you must have to override *something*

Comment: @Jamiec I edited the question.  I didnt downvote it. :-) Thanks for your valuable answer.  Please have a look at my edited question and let me know if you are able to get my question

Comment: @AneesDeen What you want to do will be of absolutely no use to you. You will *need* to do something different for each individual Get, GetAll etc. Try it - just remove the `override` in my code, and implement it in the base class. You'll soon see your idea wont work.

Comment: Thanks,  As you said I am getting an error due to constrains; I feel.  I added a screen-shot in my question.  Any suggestion?